# Show weekly and daily variations in time-series data

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, pandas, matplotlib

I've got some time-series data. I want to examine the weekly and daily variation of that data. For weekly data I can make a plot like this, with the days along the horizontal axis:

[image]

For daily data I can make a plot like this, with the hours of the day along the horizontal axis and the different colors corresponding to different days:

[image]

I've got code defined to get this information and then to plot it, but it feels cumbersome to me, like there *must* be some better, smaller, clearer way to do this. Can you see a way to simplify the code and make it smaller?

---

code:

## setup

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (17, 8)
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(context = "paper", font = "monospace")
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import sqlite3
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 500)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 500)

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

df["datetime"] = pd.datetools.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
```

## add time variables

```
df.index                    = df["datetime"]
df["weekday"]               = df["datetime"].dt.weekday
df["weekday_name"]          = df["datetime"].dt.weekday_name
df["time_through_day"]      = df["datetime"].map(lambda x: x - datetime.datetime.combine(x.date(), datetime.time()))
df["fraction_through_day"]  = df["time_through_day"].map(lambda x: x / datetime.timedelta(hours = 24))
df["hours_through_day"]     = df["fraction_through_day"] * 24
df["days_through_week"]     = df.apply(lambda row: row["weekday"] + row["fraction_through_day"], axis = 1)
df["fraction_through_week"] = df["days_through_week"] / 24
```

## rescale for plotting

```
variables_rescale = ["hash_rate", "shares"]
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df[variables_rescale] = scaler.fit_transform(df[variables_rescale])
```

## weekly variation

```
weeks = []
week  = []
previous_days_through_week = 0
for days_through_week, hash_rate in zip(df["days_through_week"], df["hash_rate"]):
    if abs(days_through_week - int(previous_days_through_week)) < 6:
        week.append([days_through_week, hash_rate])
    else:
        weeks.append(week)
        week = []
    previous_days_through_week = days_through_week
if not weeks: # < 1 week data
    weeks.append(week)

for week in weeks:
    plt.plot([datum[0] for datum in week], [datum[1] for datum in week], linestyle = "-", linewidth = 1)
plt.ylabel("hash rate")
plt.xticks(
    [     0.5,       1.5,         2.5,        3.5,      4.5,        5.5,      6.5],
    ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
);
```

## daily variation

```
days = []
day  = []
previous_hours_through_day = 0
for hours_through_day, hash_rate in zip(df["hours_through_day"], df["hash_rate"]):
    if hours_through_day < previous_hours_through_day:
        days.append(day)
        day = []
    previous_hours_through_day = hours_through_day
    day.append([hours_through_day, hash_rate])
if not days: # < 1 day data
    days.append(day)

for day in days:
    plt.plot([datum[0] for datum in day], [datum[1] for datum in day], linestyle = "-", linewidth = 1)
```

---

CSV data:

```
datetime,hash_rate,shares
2017-10-19 23:25:14,14619488,3715761
2017-10-20 00:15:45,14995173,14170275
2017-10-20 01:06:14,14351142,24030987
2017-10-20 01:56:29,14061329,3832722
2017-10-20 02:46:43,14469215,14071308
2017-10-20 03:37:02,14887834,4120626
2017-10-20 04:27:21,14576553,14530155
2017-10-20 05:17:42,14844899,24723756
2017-10-20 06:08:10,15375848,35857727
2017-10-20 06:59:26,15588730,1857548
2017-10-20 07:52:36,14519547,8854300
2017-10-20 08:45:37,15177078,361400
2017-10-20 09:37:41,14562665,11085945
2017-10-20 10:28:43,14433315,7182825
2017-10-20 11:20:22,14681236,17735705
2017-10-20 12:12:01,14400977,28116920
2017-10-20 13:04:52,14692015,39160952
2017-10-20 13:58:18,14805181,49943940
2017-10-20 14:50:31,14915132,60771876
2017-10-20 15:46:03,14249498,71992428
2017-10-20 16:38:56,14126233,82345092
2017-10-20 17:30:58,14459050,93049044
2017-10-20 18:22:45,14668601,103536024
2017-10-20 19:14:54,13657824,113764704
2017-10-20 20:07:58,14496030,124716624
2017-10-20 21:00:04,14680928,123984
2017-10-20 21:52:23,15161664,11179224
2017-10-20 22:42:59,14483703,21335580
2017-10-20 23:33:24,13263374,30717036
2017-10-21 00:23:47,14237172,41007708
2017-10-21 01:14:07,14730234,51112404
2017-10-21 02:04:38,15026071,61630380
2017-10-21 02:54:53,14224845,71580096
2017-10-21 03:45:15,14569989,81912096
2017-10-21 04:35:40,15716359,93018996
2017-10-21 05:26:08,14415618,8516770
2017-10-21 06:16:29,14115803,18676585
2017-10-21 07:06:59,14238747,28519990
2017-10-21 07:57:33,14105674,38660835
2017-10-21 08:48:18,14028049,7519655
2017-10-21 09:39:10,14249836,17586140
2017-10-21 10:30:11,14859751,28256800
2017-10-21 11:21:02,15203522,39336440
2017-10-21 12:13:49,13204020,2339337
2017-10-21 13:10:03,14643361,13651196
2017-10-21 14:04:14,14329230,10815636
2017-10-21 14:59:08,15114558,121524
2017-10-21 15:52:47,14425886,10866271
2017-10-21 16:44:24,14715853,4020419
2017-10-21 17:35:00,14546705,14380340
2017-10-21 18:26:35,14389640,7848425
2017-10-21 19:17:44,14872919,18502029
2017-10-21 20:08:25,15259542,29358173
2017-10-21 20:59:19,14437968,39738348
2017-10-21 21:50:16,14655443,49895729
2017-10-21 22:40:32,14788345,60508825
2017-10-21 23:30:51,15525346,71354842
2017-10-22 00:21:21,14184246,81340064
2017-10-22 01:11:41,14377558,91406302
2017-10-22 02:02:05,14957493,102059906
2017-10-22 02:52:30,14701035,112366488
2017-10-22 03:42:48,14863432,122746593
2017-10-22 04:33:06,14647824,132957273
2017-10-22 05:23:20,14620873,4450230
2017-10-22 06:13:50,13771920,14401125
2017-10-22 07:04:40,14459168,6946425
2017-10-22 07:56:27,14674775,17428185
2017-10-22 08:47:25,14863432,28181025
2017-10-22 09:39:02,14566972,38436885
2017-10-22 10:31:35,14607398,49212315
2017-10-22 11:25:46,15025137,6902378
2017-10-22 12:19:55,14783087,5743332
2017-10-22 13:15:06,14649431,2087244
2017-10-22 14:13:13,14929857,7690836
2017-10-22 15:06:37,15086895,18935628
2017-10-22 15:57:27,14615780,29503476
2017-10-22 16:47:47,14727951,39826872
2017-10-22 17:38:02,14694300,50084454
2017-10-22 18:28:34,14941074,60633498
2017-10-22 19:19:04,15053244,8988312
2017-10-22 20:09:43,14099797,18907422
2017-10-22 21:00:15,14335355,6882264
2017-10-22 21:50:42,14784036,17393700
2017-10-22 22:41:00,15311236,28196598
2017-10-22 23:31:20,14626997,38313150
2017-10-23 00:22:49,13920325,48288672
2017-10-23 01:14:04,13538946,56412
2017-10-23 02:04:33,14638214,10445622
2017-10-23 02:54:48,14335355,20458752
2017-10-23 03:45:07,14268053,30481284
2017-10-23 04:35:20,14032495,4371930
2017-10-23 05:25:35,14256836,1532526
2017-10-23 06:15:53,14761602,4306116
2017-10-23 07:06:07,15591661,15250044
2017-10-23 07:56:21,15558010,26128158
2017-10-23 08:46:39,14537261,36310524
2017-10-23 09:36:54,14974725,46897176
2017-10-23 10:27:19,14514827,1081230
2017-10-23 11:17:24,14896206,4954854
```

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: Python 3 is the preference, but I'd try to be compatible with 2.7 if it's easy to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Here a compact and flexible implementation using resample and plot pandas.Dataframe methods.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data.datetime)
data = data.set_index('datetime')


data.resample('d').mean().plot()

data['day'] = data.index.day
data['hour'] = data.index.hour
data_by_day = data.resample('h').mean().set_index(['day', 'hour']).unstack('day')
data_by_day['hash_rate'].plot()
data_by_day['shares'].plot()
```

[image: Output]

[pandas.Dataframe.resample method documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)